# Send a (push) message to everyone who is in the range of my Wi-Fi router?

Tags: ios, network, wifi

I have a large property and rent it out to clients who rented a holiday home. Now I would like to send to everybody an automatic message over Wi-Fi.

I have an old router with Wi-Fi, for example to let all (in the Wi-Fi range) the people know that we have today a BBQ. How could I achieve this?

Comment: WiFi itself doesn't have any capabilities to do this.  Certain OSes might (e.g. Net Send on older versions of windows) but you'd have to specify what you support.  Only thing I can think of is to change the SSID of the router (you can have up to 32 characters) and when they notice their network isn't working, they might look at the available networks and see the message.

Comment: it is also called invasion of privacy!

Comment: Flyers on their doors, maybe?

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think of doing this over wi-fi is if you have a [captive portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal), where the users have to accept a TOS each day for example - you could then amend the portal page to include your daily message. There are some open source options available but you'll likely need to purchase a dedicated router/hotspot.

Another option would be to use Bluetooth/[iBeacons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBeacon) - a lot of people leave it switched on so they can easily connect with speakers/car kits etc, and there's a lot of options available - a quick Google for "Bluetooth push advertising" or "iBeacon" should help. It's possible to [set the low cost RaspberryPi up as an iBeacon](http://learn.adafruit.com/pibeacon-ibeacon-with-a-raspberry-pi/overview), depending on your technical knowledge!

Answer (score -2):

Or use Yadwire system for in-browser injection over WiFi

Answer (score -2):

Check out www.iqwifi.net, they can help on the wifi messages etc... I've used it in my B&B it works great.